# Integrating piecewise function on an range

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
P1 = Integrate[(Abs[\[Psi]s1])^2, {x, 0,b}]
```

When I integrate the above function, I am getting an answer as below. I am not sure what's going on.
1/3 a A Conjugate[A]

Psi]s1 is same as the following piecewise function. ie,  [Psi]s1= [Psi][x, 0]
I am expecting,

[image: d]

Then only further calculations can be performed.

[image: s]

Also while integrating the modulus square of the above piece wise functions , it is showing an error.

```
 \[Psi][x_, 0] := 
     Piecewise[{{(A*x)/a, 0 <= x <= a}, {A*(b - x)/(b - a), a <= x <= b}}]
Integrate[(Abs[\[Psi][x, 0]])^2, {x, a, b}]
```

The original answer is:

[image: ss]
[image: s]

Comment: You have not provided all of the definitions, e.g., what is `\[Psi]s1`?

Comment: Edited the question by including the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Include the assumption `0 < a < b`

```
ψ[x_, 0] := 
 Piecewise[{{(A*x)/a, 0 <= x <= a}, {A*(b - x)/(b - a), a <= x <= b}}]

Assuming[0 < a < b, 
 Integrate[(Abs[ψ[x, 0]])^2, {x, 0, b}] // Simplify]

(* 1/3 b Abs[A]^2 *)

Assuming[0 < a < b, 
 Integrate[(Abs[(A*x)/a])^2, {x, 0, a}] + 
   Integrate[(Abs[A*(b - x)/(b - a)])^2, {x, a, b}] // Simplify]

(* 1/3 b Abs[A]^2 *)

Assuming[0 < a < b, 
 Integrate[(Abs[ψ[x, 0]])^2, {x, 0, a}] + 
   Integrate[(Abs[ψ[x, 0]])^2, {x, a, b}] // Simplify]

(* 1/3 b Abs[A]^2 *)
```

Comment: When I solve for the A, I am getting both positive and negative values. That means Abs is not working properly. This is because absolute value of a quantity shouldn't be negative! ie, A1 = Assuming[0 < a < b, Solve[ 1/3 *b* Abs[A]^2 == 1, Abs[A]]]

Comment: You are trying to use `Abs[A]` as if it were a variable. The `Abs` in that context doesn't get evaluated. You probably intend `A1 = Assuming[0 < a < b, Solve[{1/3 b Abs[A]^2 == 1}, A]]`

Comment: Both are giving same results! But I understood your point